# I'm trying to configure email out in wazuh but failed to do so,I followed the official doc ,using postfix also implemented the app password but failed

Tags: elasticsearch, wazuh

Here is the configuration of my wazuh manager

```
<logall json>no</logall_json>
<email_notification>yes</email_notification>
<smtp_server>smtp.gmail.com</smtp_server>
<email_from>securesally@gmail.com</email_from>
<email_to>mannupriyajb983@gmail.com</email_to>
<email_maxperhour>12</email_maxperhour>
<email_log_source>alerts.log</email_log_source>
<agents_disconnection_time>10m</agents_disconnection_time>
<agents_disconnection_alert_time>0</agents_disconnection_alert_time>
```

And this is the main.cf configuration
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587                                                                                        smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes                                                                                             smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd                                                                 smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous                                                                                smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt                                                                    smtp_use_tls = yes                                                                                                      smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination

So what to do next to make it working

Answer (score 0):

To configure alerts for a gmail account you can follow the following [documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/manager/manual-email-report/smtp-authentication.html).

I understand from your comment that you have followed the step by step of this instruction, could you then execute the following command to evaluate if the connection to the server is correct?

```
echo "Test mail from postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" -r "you@example.com" you@example.com
```

I await your comments, regards, Nicolás

Comment: This answer is more appropriate as a comment

Answer (score 0):

When configuring Wazuh using an SMTP relay server with authentication as explained in [the documentation](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/manager/manual-email-report/smtp-authentication.html) the `<smtp_server>` setting should be `localhost` instead of the gmail smtp server.

Also be sure to use an [app password](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords) instead of your gmail credentials.

As suggested by Nof, in order to verify that the relay is working correctly you may run:

```
echo "Test mail from postfix" | mail -s "Test Postfix" -r "securesally@gmail.com" mannupriyajb983@gmail.com
```

If this doesn't work then please share any errors in the `/var/log/maillog` and if this works but you're still not seeing expected email alerts by Wazuh then share the output of:

```
grep mail /var/ossec/logs/ossec.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved a similar issue, see if this helps. In your ossec.conf change
this <smtp_server>smtp.gmail.com</smtp_server> to <smtp_server>localhost</smtp_server>. When you set the SMTP server to localhost, you are instructing Wazuh to send its outbound emails to the local Postfix service running on the same server. This means Wazuh hands off the emails to Postfix, which then takes responsibility for delivering these emails to the final destination.